# Python : subclass `type` to create specialized types (e.g. a "list of int")

Tags: python, abc

I am trying to subclass `type` in order to create a class allowing to build specialized types. e.g. a `ListType` :

```
>>> ListOfInt = ListType(list, value_type=int)
>>> issubclass(ListOfInt, list)
True
>>> issubclass(list, ListOfInt)
False
>>> # And so on ...
```

However, this `ListOfInt` will never be used to create instances ! I just use it as an instance of `type` that I can manipulate to compare with other types ... In particular, in my case I need to look-up for a suitable operation, according to the type of input, and I need the type to contain more precisions (like `list of int` or `XML string`, etc ...).

So here's what I came up with :

```
class SpzType(type):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        return NotImplemented

    def __new__(cls, base, **features):
        name = 'SpzOf%s' % base.__name__
        bases = (base,)
        attrs = {}
        return super(SpzType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __init__(self, base, **features):
        for name, value in features.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

The use of `abc` is not obvious in the code above ... however if I want to write a subclass `ListType` like in the example on top, then it becomes useful ...

The basic functionality actually works :

```
>>> class SimpleType(SpzType): pass
>>> t = SimpleType(int)
>>> issubclass(t, int)
True
>>> issubclass(int, t)
False
```

But when I try to check if `t` is an instance of `SpzType`, Python freaks out :

```
>>> isinstance(t, SpzType)
TypeError: __subclasscheck__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I explored with `pdb.pm()` what was going on, and I found out that the following code raises the error :

```
>>> SpzType.__subclasscheck__(SimpleType)
TypeError: __subclasscheck__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

WeIrD ?! Obviously there is an argument ... So what does that mean ? Any idea ? Did I misuse `abc` ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `ABCMeta` as the metaclass of the constructed type, rather than of your metaclass?

Comment: If you want a language that understands parameterized types and can do compile-time type-checking, then use one. Assuming you got this working, I don't see how it could possibly gain anything over just subclassing list and rejecting non-`int`s in the interface.

Comment: @kindall: Hmm ... Yep you might be right !!! Because in my case, the instances are actually types themselves, and I probably got mixed-up with that. Thinking of it, if I want my `ListOfInt` to be detected as a subclass of `ListOfObject`, the __issubclasshook__ should be on the `ListOfObject` class . I will try tomorrow, and post the answer if it works !

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: obviously if I am doing sophisticated things like that, it is because I need to ! It is actually for a library I am writing (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/any2any/0.1), and those instances of `SpzType` are not meant to be instantiated themselves. I am just interested in defining a semantic `ListOfObject`, `JSONStr`, etc ...

Comment: @kindall: even though you might be right - and the code posted cannot achieve what I want - (I haven't tried yet), there is definitely something funky going on ... Might even be a bug, no ?

Comment: It *could* be a bug. You're traveling through the sort of the rough underbrush of Python, where very few have traveled before. But I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comment from **kindall**, I have refactored the code to the following :

```
class SpzType(abc.ABCMeta):

    def __subclasshook__(self, C):
        return NotImplemented

    def __new__(cls, base, **features):
        name = 'SpzOf%s' % base.__name__
        bases = (base,)
        attrs = {}
        new_spz = super(SpzType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_spz.__subclasshook__ = classmethod(cls.__subclasshook__)
        return new_spz

    def __init__(self, base, **features):
        for name, value in features.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

So basically, `SpzType` is now a subclass of `abc.ABCMeta`, and **subclasshook** is implemented as an instance method. It works great and it is (IMO) elegant !!!

EDIT : There was a tricky thing ... because `__subclasshook__` needs to be a classmethod, so I have to call the classmethod function manually... otherwise it doesn't work if I want to implement `__subclasshook__`.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty slick! I just wrote a solution using a decorator, which I'll post if you like, but I think you've got that beat.

Comment: I could take a look at it, because I have no idea how you would do that with a decorator !

Comment: Posted the decorator version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Maybe it is better to use `collections` module instead of using `abc` directly?

There is more info about generic collection classes in [PEP 3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#abcs-for-containers-and-iterators)

Comment: Well ... the list thing was just an example ... What I want to do is having instances of type, containing extra information. Imagine a type `XMLStr` or `JSONStr` (which `SpzType` would allow to build easily, and which would respect `issubclass(XMLStr, str) == True`) !? Imagine a type `OddInt`, ... and so on and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

The sort of thing you want to do could probably be done more easily using a class factory function like the following. At least for me, it makes it more straightforward to keep straight the various levels at which I'm trying to operate.

```
def listOf(base, types={}, **features):
    key = (base,) + tuple(features.items())
    if key in types:
        return types[key]
    else:

        if not isinstance(base, type):
            raise TypeError("require element type, got '%s'" % base)

        class C(list):

             def __init__(self, iterable=[]):
                 for item in iterable:
                     try:    # try to convert to desired type
                         self.append(self._base(item))
                     except ValueError:
                         raise TypeError("value '%s' not convertible to %s"
                            % (item, self._base.__name__))

              # similar methods to type-check other list mutations

        C.__name__ = "listOf(%s)" % base.__name__
        C._base = base
        C.__dict__.update(features)  
        types[key] = C
        return C
```

Note that I'm using a `dict` as a cache here so that you get the same class object for a given combination of element type and features.  This makes `listOf(int) is listOf(int)` always `True`.

Comment: I have tried to work like that before, but it didn't give good results, to much repetition (e.g. a factory function for `ListSpzType`, a factory function for `StrSpzType`, for `IntSpzType`, ...) and the syntax is not so nice for the end-user.

Comment: Yeah, I guess what you really need is a factory function that can make such factory functions for arbitrary base types. That would probably be as messy as what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You could pretty easily just create new child classes from a class passed in, using the `type()` constructor. Then make a class decorator for it...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decorator version of my other answer that works with any class. The decorator returns a factory function that returns a subclass of the original class with the desired attributes.  The nice thing about this approach is that it does not mandate a metaclass, so you can use a metaclass (e.g. `ABCMeta`) if desired without conflicts.

Also note that if the base class uses a metaclass, that metaclass will be used to instantiate the generated subclass. You could, if you wanted, hard-code the desired metaclass, or, you know, write a decorator that makes a metaclass into a decorator for template classes... it's decorators all the way down!

If it exists, a class method `__classinit__()` is passed the arguments passed to the factory, so the class itself can have code to validate arguments and set its attributes. (This would be called after the metaclass's `__init__()`.) If `__classinit__()` returns a class, this class is returned by the factory in place of the generated one, so you can even extend the generation procedure this way (e.g. for a type-checked list class, you could return one of two inner classes depending on whether the items should be coerced to the element type or not).

If `__classinit__()` does not exist, the arguments passed to the factory are simply set as class attributes on the new class.

For convenience in creating type-restricted container classes, I have handled the element type separately from the feature dict. If it's not passed, it'll be ignored.

As before, the classes generated by the factory are cached so that each time you call for a class with the same features, you get the same class object instance.

```
def template_class(cls, classcache={}):

    def factory(element_type=None, **features):

        key = (cls, element_type) + tuple(features.items())
        if key in classcache:
            return classcache[key]

        newname  = cls.__name__
        if element_type or features:
            newname += "("
            if element_type:
                newname += element_type.__name__
                if features:
                    newname += ", "
            newname += ", ".join(key + "=" + repr(value)
                                 for key, value in features.items())
            newname += ")"

        newclass = type(cls)(newname, (cls,), {})
        if hasattr(newclass, "__classinit__"):
            classinit = getattr(cls.__classinit__, "im_func", cls.__classinit__)
            newclass = classinit(newclass, element_type, features) or newclass
        else:
            if element_type:
                newclass.element_type = element_type
            for key, value in features.items():
                setattr(newclass, key, value)

        classcache[key] = newclass
        return newclass

    factory.__name__ = cls.__name__
    return factory
```

An example type-restricted (type-converting, actually) list class:

```
@template_class
class ListOf(list):

    def __classinit__(cls, element_type, features):
        if isinstance(element_type, type):
            cls.element_type = element_type
        else:
            raise TypeError("need element type")

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            try:
                self.append(self.element_type(item))
            except ValueError:
                raise TypeError("value '%s' not convertible to %s"
                        % (item, self.element_type.__name__))

    # etc., to provide type conversion for items added to list
```

Generating new classes:

```
Floatlist = ListOf(float)
Intlist   = ListOf(int)
```

Then instantiate:

```
print FloatList((1, 2, 3))       # 1.0, 2.0, 3.0
print IntList((1.0, 2.5, 3.14))  # 1, 2, 3
```

Or just create the class and instantiate in one step:

```
print ListOf(float)((1, 2, 3))
print ListOf(int)((1.0, 2.5, 3.14))
```

Comment: I would add that this looks a lot longer than your solution, but much of the extra code involves making sure that the generated class has a `__name__` attribute that reflects the features used in the class. For example, try `print ListOf(int, convert=True)` Adding this to a metaclass wouldn't be any less code.

Comment: Thanks ! It is longer, and some parts seem a bit hackish :-P but it does look good in the end !